# Create a collage of images on a defined area

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I want to create a collage of images on a defined area. Since I have a big number of images, I am looking for a algorithm that can solve this problem. **The goal of this algorithm should be to maximize the area that is covered by the images**.

There are also **two rules** that should be met:

**1.)** It is allowed to resize the images but only proportionally (avoid ‚squeezing‘, lock the aspect ratio).

**2.)** There must be a maximum and minimum height and width (in order to avoid that some photos are unproportionally big compared to others and to prevent the algorithm from shrinking a photo to a size where you can‘t see the image anymore).

I have also a two (optional) goals that should be solved by the algorithm:

**3.)** The images should have as much contact to the borders as possible.

**4.)** I am not not able to define the second goal algorithmically, so please excuse my loose language here:The algorithm should try to create a ‚pretty‘ distribution of the images. For example, one *could* agree that the second collage looks prettier than the first one, because there is a more harmonic ratio between the number of 'uncovered-area-shapes' and their size. Also, in contrast to the first example, the uncovered-area-shapes in the second example take up the shape of rectangles which makes the whole image look 'more calm':

[image]

Comment: How big is the big number? Is it required to use all the images?

Comment: Around 500-1500 images. Yes, I would like to use all the images. I could use less if this is helpful for solving the problem computationally.